# Corollary 2.4.11. from Analysis Now by Pedersen - bad proof?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Here is a small excerpt from *Analysis Now* by Pedersen:

> **2.4.10. Proposition.** *Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a normed space and $\mathfrak{Z}$ be a w*-closed subspace of $\mathfrak{X}^\ast$. For every $\psi$ in $\mathfrak{X}^\ast\backslash\mathfrak{Z}$ there is an $x$ in $\mathfrak{Z}^\perp$ such that $\langle x,\psi \rangle \neq 0$.*
>
> Proof. (...)
>
> **2.4.11. Corollary.** *Every w*-closed subspace of $\mathfrak{X}^\ast$ has the form $\mathfrak{Y}^\perp$ for some norm closed subspace $\mathfrak{Y}$ of $\mathfrak{X}$.*

Why does the corollary follow? Here is my attempt:

---

For $\mathfrak{S}$ w*-closed in $\mathfrak{X}^\ast$ then take $S\subseteq \mathfrak{X}$  as $\mathfrak{S}^\perp\triangleq \{x|\forall\phi \in \mathfrak{S},\ \langle x, \phi \rangle=0\}$ Considering that each of these $\phi$ is continuous, $S$ is clearly a norm-closed subspace of $\mathfrak{X}$. Using the contrapositive of 2.4.10 on $S$, then we have that if some $\psi$ is $0$ along all $S$ then $\psi$ must be in $\mathfrak{S}.$

---

I am scared I have used a tautology somewhere and assumed the claim. Are there any gaps?

Comment: This is okay. However, what do you mean be the strange formulation *negating the converse*?

Comment: the contrapositive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$